# Confusion on MVC in swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, architecture

I have a class that takes care of all network request. So my confusion is where should i call this network request class either from viewcontroller or model class. Suppose i have 'User' model class with properties id,name,phone. In order to access login API, should i create a function 'loginwithphone' within this model class and call it from viewcontroller or should i call network request class directly from Viewcontroller. Is the network request class considered as a model in itself? If so, calling it from viewcontroller will still make my code architecture as MVC. Doesnt it?

Comment: The right way to call network call is from view controller not from model class

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to **Observer pattern** which defines MVC architecture, to define any way to manage your request through callbacks.

Model layer of MVC architecture defines your POJOS, so 'loginwithphone' function should be in a controller class, for example 'logincontroller'.
To sum up, your network request class should be considered as a class inside a resources layer. and should call your controller class.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In MVC you should call the network request through a networking class. Preferably you will first run a class or enum that will build the request for you. After that you will get the model object returned to you that you will have stored in your viewController and send to all the views you want to populate.

Off-topic: I like MVVM as you then call another class (viewModel) which holds all the models and the requests, and all you have in your viewController are views and callbacks waiting for the viewModel to finish it's requests.

Example:

```
//ViewController
self.viewModel.fetchData()
self.viewModel.dataFetched = {
view.populate(withData: self.viewModel.datas)
}

//ViewModel
var dataFetched: (() -> ())?
var datas: [Data] = []
func fetchData() {
let request = networkManager.buildRequest()
sendRequest( success: { datas in
self.datas = datas
dataFetched?()
})
}
```

This is a very vague description of how its done. But i like this way